# Chrome Caching breaks checkout after SUPEE-9767

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, supee-9767

We're having a strange issue on our client's shops after applying the SUPEE-9767 patch and updating the theme files.

Apparently many of their customers are using Chrome, which is caching the old form, and the form-key is not being submitted. This results in the checkout process halting after entering the CC information.

We're sending the following headers:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

...but it looks like Chrome is ignoring them.

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Make sure you clear all your Magento caches including flushing the JavaScript/CSS cache.

Comment: flush magento cache , flush js css cache

Comment: We flush the caches after any code change; thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would [make sure that the js updates are present in your theme](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Checkout-Stuck-on-Step-4-after-SUPEE-9767-with-Formkey/m-p/68018).

Beyond that, I'm no aware of a solution to browser caching other than having the user hard refresh (Ctrl-Shift-R). Maybe if you updated the timestamp (i.e. `touch` on all js files) then the browser would consider the files necessary to download.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the theme JS looks okay on each site. I wish there was a way to request that the browser dumps it's cache for the site, but if it ignores the headers...